# Unable to run GNOME Shell.

Tags: gnome, thinkpad

I used terminal to install Gnome shell (sudo apt-get install gnome-shell) and restarted, but when I log on using 'GNOME', the Background and icons on the desktop load, but the gnome panel and the one at the top cease to load. Help please.

I am using:

An IBM Thinkpad R50e, 32-bit, Intel Celeron M processor, Intel® 852GM/855GM x86/MMX/SSE2 graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to upgrade the graphics. Gnome Shell requires hardware acceleration, which Intel's 8xx GPUs do not have.